# Using \only in beamer for a figure: figure doesn't stay in place

Tags: beamer, floats

I want to replace one of the two figures, so I'm using `\only` quite often. What I observe is that the figure is moving to the right. In the snippet below I'm using the same image file to make sure it's not because of different widths of the images.
Why is the figure moving right slightly every slide and how can I fix it?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{$H$-Methode - Beispiel}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns

\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\textbf{Liste von Paaren $(\alpha,\beta)$}\\
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1>$V.\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{m-n+1}.\Sigma_I^i$
    \item<2-3>\only<1-2>{$(aa,b)$}\only<3->{$(aa,b) \rightarrow a$}
    \item<4-5>\only<1-4>{$(aa,\epsilon)$}\only<5->{$(aa,\epsilon) \rightarrow b$}
    \item<6-7>\only<1-6>{$(ba,a)$}\only<7->{$(ba,a) \rightarrow a$}
    \item<8-9>\only<1-8>{$(ba,\epsilon)$}\only<9->{$(ba,\epsilon) \rightarrow a$}
    \item<10-11>\only<1-10>{$(ab,a)$}\only<11->{$(ab,a) \rightarrow a$}
    \item<12-13>\only<1-12>{$(bb,a)$}\only<13->{$(bb,a) \rightarrow b$}
  \end{itemize}
\end{column}%

\begin{column}{.70\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/fsm-example01_orig}
\only<1-2>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<4>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<5>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<6>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<7>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<8>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<9>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<10>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<11>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<12>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<13>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\only<14>{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{images/HTree01}}
\end{column}%

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: put `%` at the ends of the lines, you are adding space after each hidden image

Comment: Your columns are too wide. The sum of .4 and .7 exceeds the available textwidth.

Comment: @samcarter I would have expected that `width=0.4\textwidth` acts locally and takes 40 % of `\begin{column}{.70\textwidth}`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner For the image yes, but the sum of both column widths is too big.

Comment: @samcarter Sorry - didn't see it. You are right!

Comment: Yes, the width is too big. But it doesn't matter for this problem. The solution is what @DavidCarlisle mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `%` at the ends of the lines, you are adding space after each hidden image

Comment: why not as an answer instead of a comment :) accepted and thanks.